# Why is a private field accessible and a private setter not accessible from a static method?

Tags: c#

The following gives me a compiler error:

```
    private ObservableEventListener Listener { get; private set; }

    public static void Register()
    {
        Log.Listener = new ObservableEventListener();
        Log.Listener.EnableEvents(Log, EventLevel.LogAlways, EventKeywords.None); 
    }
```

> Error 26  The accessibility modifier of the 'MyEventSource.Listener.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'MyEventSource.Listener'

But this compiles just fine:

```
    private ObservableEventListener Listener;

    public static void Register()
    {
        Log.Listener = new ObservableEventListener();
        Log.Listener.EnableEvents(Log, EventLevel.LogAlways, EventKeywords.None);

    }
```

It seems there is more security around the backing setter methods?  There are always redundant lines of code/warnings.. why is this an error?

Comment: You've already declared `Listener` as `private`, so the `private` on the setter is redundant.  Remove it.

Comment: Did you try it without the "private" on `set`? Its already a private member, so doubling the conditional doesn't do anything, and is probably freaking out the compiler based on the error rule given.

Comment: ok, but why is it an error?  There are always redundant lines of code/warnings.. why is this an error?

Comment: private is not *more restrictive* than private, so its an error. It *shouldn't* be an error, but compilers are picky.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes, it should be an error: the modifier here is **required** to be "more restrictive". private is not more restrictive than private, thus it fails

Comment: why a down vote on a perfectly good question?

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess the requirement just seems silly (that its not >=, but strictly >), but yes, it is absolutely an error via the spec.

Comment: thanks for the answers, comments.  While I understand the rule I think making it an error yet unused variables/etc are warnings seems backwards...

Comment: @TMcKeown that's easy to fix: `/warnaserror+` - there you go: now they're all equally picky ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified `private` on the setter, which is normally fine, except you made the member `private` as well.

`private` is not more restrictive than `private`, which violates the rule quoted in the error, namely that:

> The accessibility modifier of the 'MyEventSource.Listener.set'
>   accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer
>   'MyEventSource.Listener'

Perhaps the language designers should have allowed equal restrictiveness, but they didn't, so the compile fails.

Comment: I chose this error because I agree with your comments!! =)

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, the only sensible answer here is "because the language designers specified that the accessibility statement on property accessors must be more restrictive than the property itself". That is the entirely of why it is an error. Why they chose that... well, you could try reading the annotated specification, but... meh.

I guess it simply makes *no sense* to have a `public` modifier on a `private` property, so clearly *less restrictive* (more accessible) is nonsensical; and equally restrictive is redundant: you are adding keywords presumably with an intent to do something, and it will have no result - so probably an error.

Comment: Heh, you don't even need to read the spec.  The compiler error spells it out.

Answer (score 6):

As it is usually the case with questions about compilation, the answer is because the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms228593.aspx) says so!

Section 10.7.2 (emphasis mine)

> - The accessor-modifier **must declare an accessibility that is strictly more restrictive than the declared accessibility of the property or indexer itself**. To be precise:
>
>   - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of public, the accessor-modifier may be either protected internal,
>       internal, protected, or private.
>   - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of protected internal, the accessor-modifier may be either internal,
>       protected, or private.
>   - If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of internal or protected, the accessor-modifier must be private.
>   - **If the property or indexer has a declared accessibility of private, no accessor-modifier may be used.**

Comment: +1 for finding the relevant portion of the spec. +1 again (if I could) for finding that *this exact scenario* is listed in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Placing access modifier on a getter or setter is intended to allow you to restrict it further than the proeprty as a whole is declared.  Therefore it doesn't make sense to take a private property and then try to make its setter private, because it's already private.

Proper usage, public getter, private setter:

```
public ObservableEventListener Listener { get; private set; }
^^ What you want BOTH Get/Setter to be         ^^ but you can make one more restrictive
```

Wrong:

```
private ObservableEventListener Listener { get; private set; }
^^ You want BOTH Get/Setter private             ^^ So what does this mean if you already made them private?
```